# How do i check if a php variable($stat_ip) containing an ip address(inet_aton) lies in the range of two ip's(inet_aton format)

Tags: php, mysql

//the variable $stat_ip lies in the table Hasoffers which is to be checked if it lies between the column values network_start_ip and network_end_ip, which lie in another table called Blacklisted.I need to write a function which helps me do the same by accessing all three.

```
 <?php
        include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
        mysql_connect("*****","***","***");
        mysql_select_db("********");
        $pl=mysql_query("SELECT stat_ip,stat_session_ip FROM Hasoffers");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($pl)

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pl))
              {
               $stat_ip=$row['stat_ip'];

               echo fn($stat_ip)."<br>";
              }

          $bip=mysql_query("SELECT inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_end_ip) FROM blacklisted");

          while($array=mysql_fetch_array($bip))
          {
            $start_ip=$array['network_Start_ip'];
            $end_ip = $array['netwrok_end_ip'];

          }


          function fn($stat_ip)
             {
                $result =mysql_query('SELECT stat_ip FROM Hasoffers where ($stat_ip BETWEEN INET_ATON(network_start_ip) AND INET_ATON(network_end_ip)');





        }
        ?>php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use between

```
SELECT inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_end_ip) 
FROM blacklisted
WHERE your_ip_column  BETWEEN INET_ATON(network_start_ip) AND INET_ATON(network_end_ip)
```

If you need  both the query in a single select you could use a left join on between

```
SELECT a.stat_ip 
FROM Hasoffers as a 
LEFT JOIN blacklisted on  as b on inet_aton(a.stat_ip)  
              between INET_ATON(b.network_start_ip) AND INET_ATON(b.network_end_ip)
```

Comment: but how do i access my ip column as well as the columns of the other table( network_start_ip & network end_ip) simultaneously. As they belong to two different tables.

Comment: Answer  updated  .. hope is what you are looking for